# MOSFET Circuit to Detect 28V to control an MP1584 enable pin - is my solution viable?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, inverter

My circuit's goal is to detect presence/absence of 28V on an input and operate the EN (enable) pin of a MP1584 voltage regulator. My circuit seems functional to me but I'd appreciate other opinions of its viability.

My intent is to have the MP1584's EN pin 2 floating such that it is biased high by its internal 3V/1uA source. When the 28V being monitored is at 28V, I want to pull the EN pin below 1.2V to disable the MP1584.

I've considered using a 74LVC1G06GV,125 inverter but feel that using the BS170F MOSFET inverter would be simpler and use less PCB real estate.

[image]

Comment: What about the range of input voltages on the 28 volt line that should keep the MP1584 enabled or disabled. What do you want to achieve in this shadow area?

Comment: Any particular reason not to use a comparator with hysteresis for this task?

Comment: There is no range of input voltages on the 28 volt line - it is a digitally switched power line that is either 28V or high impedance open. It is not the Vcc for the MP1584 but I want it controlled by it.

Comment: Re comparator, I haven't explored that. My goal is (1) simplicity; (2) minimal PCB real estate consumed on an already tight board.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what happens if the MOSFET were ideal so that when on it’s a short from drain to source. You would have the 2.7 M resistor grounded. Now how much voltage will there be across it at 1 uA?

Ideally the lowest your enable pin would go is 2.7 V. Lose the resistor, you don’t need current limiting there.

Comment: GodJihyo, Thank you for your response. As you point out, the end of the resistor at the EN pin will be too positive to disable the IC. My original, flawed thinking for the current limiting resistor was because the manufacturer's specs don't disclose what internal circuitry is limiting the 3V to 1uA nor if it has protection from excess current draw which may be the case if the MOSFET makes a hard connection to GND. I just sent that question to the manufacturer's support group but who knows if I will get a response.

Comment: @remoc What difference does it make what the internal circuitry is? It says it's internally limited to 1uA, you can either believe them or not. It says in your image the goal is to pull EN to 0 V,  that's a hard connection to ground.

Comment: I agree. You are correct.